# How to tag a class with another class type?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm writing a lighting software, and I need help modeling one aspect of it.
I have a `Pixel` interface, from which `DimmerPixel`, `ColorPixel` and `PanTiltPixel` inherit. Then, I have a `PixelMap` class, that has an array of `Pixel`.

[image: uml]

What I need to acomplish is:

- A `PixelMap` should store only one type of `Pixel`.
- Being able to create a polymorphic array of `PixelMap` with different `Pixel` types.
- Being able to compare the `Pixel` type of two `PixelMap` objects.

That led me to think `PixelMap` should be a template class, then I've tried this:

```
class PixelMap_t {};

template <class T>
class PixelMap : PixelMap_t {}
```

`PixelMap_t` is a type used to store polymorphic arrays of `PixelMap`. But I couldn't find any way to retrieve the type of the object `PixelMap<T>` from it's polymorphic pointer `PixelMap_t*`.

The smelly solution I can think of is manually writing classes `DimmerPixelMap`, `ColorPixelMap` and etc. I'd really like to avoid it, since there are at least 20 more `___Pixel` classes to come.

I know it's also possible to store a custom metadata on the `Pixel` class, and use the first `Pixel` on the array of the `PixelMap` to determine it's type, but i feel like I should use metadata provided by the language itself.

Also, if the `PixelMap` class knows the `Pixel` type it's storing (and not some string metadata), it can create a contiguous array of `___Pixel`, instead of an array of `Pixel*` that reference non-contiguous memory. That is a huge performance leap considering I'll be constantly iterating those arrays.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

The cleanest way I've found so far is:

```
class PixelMap_t {
  public:
    virtual const std::type_info& getType() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class PixelMap : public PixelMap_t {
  public:
    const std::type_info& getType() { return typeid(T); }
}
```

As a footnote, as noted [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

```
assert(pixelMapA.getType() == pixelMapB.getType()); // not guaranteed
assert(pixelMapA.getType().hash_code() == pixelMapB.getType().hash_code()); // guaranteed
```

Comment: It's probably a software architecture question, not stackoverflow question :3

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie do you recommend a better place for such questions? I wasn't aware, sorry if it's misplaced.

Comment: _I couldn't find any way to retrieve the type of the object PixelMap<T> from it's polymorphic pointer PixelMap_t*_ - Why do you want to do that? Your first attempt at templates looks fine provided `PixelMap_t` is a private implementation detail of `PixelMap<>`. With that design you should never use `PixelMap_t` in client code. Use only `PixelMap<WhateverPixel>`.

Comment: @IgorG I must be able to create arrays of `PixelMap<T>`, with different T types, and there's a method that blends those arrays based on the T type, so it must compare them in pairs by type.
In my understanding, it's not possible to do `template class<T> std::vector<PixelMap<T>*>`, only `std::vector<PixelMap_t*>`. Is there another way around I'm not seeing?